# Migrating a WordPress site has broken UTF8 encoding

Tags: migration, encoding

I am trying to migrate a WordPress site from one server to another, but on the new server I'm getting incorrect symbols in place of UTF8 (I assume) characters.

I dumped the database using `mysqldump`:

```
mysqldump mydb -r /var/www/vhosts/mysite/database.sql
```

I then sent it to the new server using `rsync`:

```
rsync -r -a -v -e ssh --delete --no-perms --omit-dir-times /var/www/vhosts/mysite user@targetserver:/var/www/vhosts/
```

I then created a new DB on the new server:

```
DROP DATABASE wpdb;
CREATE DATABASE wpdb;
GRANT ALL privileges ON wpdb.* TO "wp"@"%" IDENTIFIED BY "password";
FLUSH privileges;
```

And then imported the data:

```
SET names 'utf8mb4';
SOURCE /var/www/vhosts/mysite/database.sql;
```

If I use the mysql client to pull out some sample posts, I see the correct symbols. If I look at the `SHOW CREATE` for the posts table at both ends, they both show

```
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

I don't know how else to ensure UTF8 throughout the pipeline.

---

I have compared various stages of the process. For example, if I look at the `database.sql` dump at both ends for an offending piece of text, I see:

```
 pages we can tell you who’s ready
```

On both sides, so I don't think it's `mysqldump` or the `rsync`.

I then look in the database by simply using the mysql client and querying the posts table:

```
pages we can tell you who’s ready
```

So it seems to have ended up in the DB okay.

On-screen though:

```
pages we can tell you who�s ready
```

Could it be a PHP setting?

Comment: Seems I got migrated. I didn't even think of looking for a WP.SE :)

Comment: it is because the utf8mb4 is an extended set of characters. Your MySQL will probably only have the utf8 set installed and not the extended set so characters will go missing or not match when you import.

Comment: Would that not show when I tried to `set names` or in the `show create` though?

Comment: It would cause any number of problems when you're trying to set UTF8 characters is a UTF8mb4 setting

Comment: What I mean is, if I try to create a table with the utf8mb4 charset on a server without it, I'd expect an error.